# Grails dependency - all commands hang

Tags: grails

No matter what grails command I run, it hangs. 
I turn on verbose logging - end of message is...

```
        tried /Users/me/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.8-SNAPSHOT/htmlunit-2.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
        tried /Users/me/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.8-SNAPSHOT/htmlunit-2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
    localMavenResolver: no ivy file nor artifact found for net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.8-SNAPSHOT
don't use cache for net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.8-SNAPSHOT: changing=true
```

Any ideas what's up?

Comment: Can you show `BuildConfig`? Make sure you are able to access the repos properly. Also to be on the brighter side try cleaning and building project. If required, clean them manually from USER_HOME as well.

Comment: Similar things happened to me, My antivirus was causing the issue. Try disabling your AV and see if that solves the issue, you can then configure AV to exclude your maven and ivy cache directories.